# Selector for an element right after a class

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I want to style a `span` that is right after a `span` with a class `.pin`, but I have no idea which selector can do it.

`.pin + span` does not work for me (as it is probably not designed to handle classes at the end of the call).

My HTML:

```
<span class="pin">
  <i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>
</span>
<span>
  Some text
</span>
```

Comment: create a fiddle demo?

Comment: Like this http://jsfiddle.net/akshay7/1so6er9k/ ?

Comment: add a new class to span or use inline styles

Comment: @Akshay, even the original one works http://jsfiddle.net/1so6er9k/1/

Comment: Are you sure `.pin + span` does not work? It certainly works with the markup you have given. And it should work even if the second element has a class.

Comment: @AmmarCSE Didn't try that

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a new class for the second span

Answer (score 1):

add a new class to span or use inline styles

HTML

```
<span class="pin">
  <i class="fa fa-map-marker">Italic Text</i>
</span>
<span class='nextPin'>
  Some text
</span>
```

css

```
.pin {
    color: red;
}

.nextPin {
    color: blue;    
}
```

working fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/kb6bwcjo/)

Comment: Please give an example with your recommendation next time

Comment: It came up as a recommendation for deletion thats why I said something

Comment: @SethMcClaine Thanks for saving it from deletion

Answer (score 1):

Everything works in 3-ways:
http://jsfiddle.net/1so6er9k/4/
CSS:

```
div:nth-child(1) > .pin + span {
     color:red;
}
div:nth-child(2) > .pin ~ span {
     color:red;
}

div:nth-child(3) {
    color: red;
}
div:nth-child(3) > .pin{
    color: black
}
```

HTML:

```
<div>
    <span class="pin"><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i></span><span>Some text</span>
</div>
<div>
    <span class="pin"><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i></span><span>Some text</span>
</div>
<div>
    <span class="pin"><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i></span><span>Some text</span>
</div>
```

Tested on:
IE 11.0.9600,
FF 38.0.1,
Chrome 43.0.2357.81 on 
Widnows 7 x64

Maybe you should not use nested selector. Now you do not necessarily need to use it. Consider you not to use nested selector. This prevents the use of the class again and make stylesheets bigger.

Answer (score 0):

You can use  Jquery code given below if you want to apply css to next span without assigning new class to it

```
$( ".pin ~ span" ).css( "color", "blue" ).val( "Some text" );
```

Above code will add CSS to next sibling element of element having class="pin"

- Ideally you should add class to next span and then apply various css styling for it.It reduces code complexity and make code more readable and maintainable.

Answer (score 0):

you can give inline styling like

```
<span style="color:blue; font-size:80%;">
  Some text
</span>
```

or you can give different class to the second span and then give styling to that class. Like:

```
<span class="span2">
  Some text
</span>
```

in head section

```
<style>
.span2{
color:red;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a good question.

The [W3C CSS specification definition](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors/#adjacent-sibling-combinators) for this *combinator*:

> The **next-sibling combinator** is made of the “plus sign” (U+002B, +) code point that separates two compound selectors. The elements represented by the two compound selectors share the same parent in the document tree and the element represented by the first compound selector immediately precedes the element represented by the second one. Non-element nodes (e.g. text between elements) are ignored when considering the adjacency of elements.

Definition of *compound selector* is as follows:

> A compound selector is a sequence of simple selectors that are not separated by a combinator, and represents a set of simultaneous conditions on a single element. If it contains a type selector or universal selector, that selector must come first in the sequence. Only one type selector or universal selector is allowed in the sequence. (A compound selector is represented by  in the selectors grammar.) A given element is said to match a compound selector when it matches all simple selectors in the compound selector.

From this, one may infer that the class selector by itself would simply be a *simple selector*, as it *does not* represent a set of simultaneous conditions on a single element. However, if you have a look at the first example provided in the specification document, you will notice that it uses simple selectors *only* with the combinator, as valid CSS:

> Examples: The following selector represents a p element immediately following a math element:
> math + p

Although these are type selectors, in my opinion, they are still simple selectors. As such, the definition is perhaps in need of an update. So, reading the specification doesn't really help to explain why a class by itself is treated differently when used with the next-sibling combinator (apparently also known as the ***adjacent sibling combinator***).

Regardless, if you want to select an element of a particular type immediately after a specific class with a specific type, you only need to provide a type immediately prior to the class. For example:

```
span.pin + span
```

It is also possible to apply psuedo-classes, such as `:hover`, to a class using the next-sibling combinator. The following example will cause the second span element to change in some way, when the first span element is hovered over with a mouse pointer. Note that this does not require a type to come before the class:

```
.pin:hover + span
```

With the two examples I have given above, the simple class selector effectively becomes a compound selector. However, the span type selector on the far right is still a simple selector.